# Factory state recovery with RAID0-SSDs

Tags: laptop

Because of the usual security issues, I will try to reset my ASUS UX51VZ notebook to its factory state. Of course, this wont make any sense, if the main partition is not going to be formatted (=physically resetted). My questions are - if I use the factory state recovery function of the notebook, which is stored on another partition of the SSD drive, will this function format my main partition before setting up Win 8 again?

Also, the drives are configured as RAID-0 by factory default. Will this state be transferred to the new Windows configuration after factory state recovery?